# What are some methods to manage a constant & persistent temptation or urge towards a bad habit like smoking, eating junk food?

Tags: addiction, self-control, feeding, self-discipline, willpower

This questions is around my observation of my own behavioral pattern. I am quite good at avoiding junk foods on some days and on others, I am miserably fail.

I have some mild clinical depression and anxiety, and so I have good & bad days in that context too.

On bad days(depression or anxiety), I crave for junk food especially sugar(sometimes booze & smoke too). I am usually able to keep myself off of them for a couple of hours, I employ various techniques like taking a walk, eating veggies, meditating but even after hours, when urge do not go away, I finally give up.

The way I give up is quite interesting too, I just eat fast or do so in a fashion that I won't let me think about it or put an argument against it. It feels like my mind is hijacked or possessed and the worst thing is I end up eating twice(or much more) of what might have satisfied me on a normal day e.g. 10 cookies instead 1.

**I believe the problem is not only about resisting the urge but resisting it for long enough like a day without adding any more intensity to it(longer I resist and stronger they get).**

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  This question is clearly soliciting opinion-based answers, so I'm going to close it.  Please edit it to ask for an evidence based answer to a more specific question, and then it can be reopened.

Comment: For the same reason, I removed the current responses. This type of Q&A is not what this site is for.

Comment: Sorry, I will change the words of my question.However my intention was not putting question soliciting opinion based answers, although now apparently it appears as such. I was fascinated by the concept/research of implementation intentions introduced in 1999 by psychologist Peter Gollwitzer and wanted to gather more techniques like that.ref :https://psycnet.apa.org/doiLanding?doi=10.1037%2F0003-066X.54.7.493 . Thanks